# Page inside page with ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I would like to open an external page within my page using ajax, I tried in several ways, I used the iframe tag, but it didn't meet my need, I researched and saw that with ajax I think it will, but I don't know how to do it.Can anybody help me?

Comment: iframe and AJAX are generally unrelated to each other most of the time. It's a bit unclear _precisely_ what the situation is and what outcome you want, and it's certainly unclear what you've tried or what went wrong, because you haven't shown us. Context is everything. Take the [tour], read [ask] and how to create a [mre] of your issue, and then edit your question to show your specific problem / issue. Further reading:  [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is the syntax to make an ajax call

```
$.ajax({url: "path/to/file", success: function(result){
    console.log(result);
}});
```

But you have to be more specific on your question.

Comment: My Final goal is to open a page inside my page, because I don't want the user to see the page link, I tried to use the iframe, I got it, but the page is constantly updating, now I'm trying to use ajax, but now it's loading without to stop.